# Shell provision doesn't run sed command

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I want to run 2 commands below to make terminal colorful. They work on terminal, but not in shell script.

bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

If I append **apt-get update** at the end, only apt-get update is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vagrant's shell provisioner][1] runs with `privileged = true` by default:

> privileged (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script
>   as a privileged user or not (sudo). By default this is "true".

When you perform `vagrant ssh` you login to a VM as `vagrant` user.

That's why:

> ```
> sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" ~/.bashrc
> ```

did changes in `root's` `~/.bashrc`.

**Solution:** execute `sed` to `vagrant's` home folder's `.bashrc`:

```
sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

Your final `bootstrap.sh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/g" /home/vagrant/.bashrc
. /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```